# Paste values not working in workbook - Numbers pasted as text need to be converted to numbers

Tags: database, excel, paste

I copied a downloaded spreadsheet that has a bunch of data in it, numbers and text mixed. I've done this before but I'm not sure how I did it since it seems I can't recreate it.

So I copied and pasted the data into my workbook. I pasted values and everything with a number has an error flag saying that the number is stored as text. Somehow I was able to do it before where it just pasted the values with formatting as General and everything did not have an error flag.

Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it depends on how the data is originally stored. If it was stored as text, then you'll get text no matter how you paste it. You'll need to convert the text to numbers.

There are a couple of ways of doing this:

If your spreadsheet has a couple of columns, you can use Text-to-Columns:

1. Select 1 column at a time
2. Click Data > Text to Columns
3. Click Next and untick all Delimiters
4. Click Finish
5. Repeat for each column

If your spreadsheet has lots of columns, it's quicker to use a Paste-Special trick:

1. In an unused cell, enter a value of 1
2. Copy it
3. Select all of the data you downloaded
4. Right click on the data and choose Paste Special
5. In the Operation section, choose multiply
6. Click OK

Excel then tries to multiple everything by one. Anything that looks like a number get converted to a number so it can be multiplied by 1, which then doesn't change the number any further.

Note: If you have blank cells, they'll be converted to zeroes. If this is a problem, then use the following steps instead:

1. In an unused cell, enter a value of 1
2. Copy it
3. Select all of the data you downloaded
4. Click Ctrl-G
5. Click Speical
6. Select Constants then click OK. You should now have only cells with data selected.
7. Right click one of the selected cells and choose Paste Special
8. In the Operation section, choose multiply
9. Click OK

Comment: You're welcome. As this solves your issue, can you please mark the answer as accepted so that the question is marked as resolved? Thanks.